# Set breakpoint to catch variable deallocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a variable that references a UIView.

> UIView *someView;

That UIView is on screen the entire time in question.
This variable is somehow being set to nil at some point and I can't figure out where, because there's only a single line of code in my whole class that where the UIView variable is set to nil, and I've set a breakpoint on that and discovered it's not that line that is causing my UIView variable to go nil.

I don't believe my UIView is a stack variable either, as it's declared in the @interface between the {} as an ivar

So my problem is trying to figure out how this variable is going nil.

How can I solve this?

Comment: is your UIView assigned to a weak variable and is it an `@IBOutlet`? try show some code

Comment: Write a setter which you place a breakpoint in. If you can not find the root of the issue, please post code.

Comment: @shallowThought --- That's not shallow.... that's DEEP.  Don't know how I missed that idea.  I'm going to try that, along with a huge slap to the forehead.